# How to retrieve path of catalina.out in java program?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, tomcat6

I need to get the path of catalina.out file which is configured in the logging.properties.

Is there a way to retrieve the property "1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory" via java without knowing the path to the properties file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, then you want to read an attribute of the Tomcat `logging.properties` file. As you can see here in the [Tomcat FAQ for Logging](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Logging), `java.util.logging.config.file` is used to define the path to the property file.

You can then retrieve this path via [Java System Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html):

```
String pathLogProps = System.getProperty("java.util.logging.config.file");
Properties properties = new Properties();
try {
     properties.load(new FileInputStream(pathLogProps));
     System.out.println(prop.getProperty("database"));
} catch (IOException ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

If this is not set, I would follow the hints from the [Apache Tomcat 7 Logging Documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html):

> JULI is enabled by default, and supports per classloader
>   configuration, in addition to the regular global java.util.logging
>   configuration. This means that logging can be configured at the
>   following layers:
>
> - Globally. That is usually done in the `${catalina.base}/conf/logging.properties` file. The file is specified
>     by the java.util.logging.config.file System property which is set by
>     the startup scripts.
> - If it is not readable or is not configured, the default is to use the `${java.home}/lib/logging.properties` file in the JRE. In the web
>     application. The file will be `WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties`

Per default the path to the `logging.properties` file should be available over the environment variable `catalina.base`, respectively `CATALINA_BASE`.

Comment: good approach, but I don't get the property "java.util.logging.config.file" - I just receive null...

Comment: @reini122 I've added another paragraph. If the system variable is not set it should at least be available over the Java or Catalina environment variable.

Comment: Thank you very much, reading logging.properties via catalina.base works!

Answer (score 1):

The file `catalina.out` is specified neither in any system property, nor is is specified in `logging.properties` (take a [look](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk/conf/logging.properties?view=markup), it isn't there).

Instead, `catalina.out` is created by the launching script's shell-based output redirection from within `bin/catalina.sh` (or `bin/catalina.bat`). That means that this file is only available if you have launched Tomcat using those scripts, or scripts that emulate this behavior. For example, if you use `jsvc` on a *NIX platform, or the Tomcat Windows Service, then the file `logs/catalina.out` does not get created (at least not by default).

If you want to take a peek to see if the file exists, you can bet on it being in `$CATALINA_BASE/logs/catalina.out`. Recent versions of Tomcat define the `catalina.base` system property so you can easily take a look like this:

```
File catalinaOut = new File(System.getProperty("catalina.base"), "logs/catalina.out");
if(catalinaOut.exists())
{
    // Do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, it is exactly what I'm doing now. I'm reading out the path via catalina.base and "guess" that the file is there. If not I can't do anything, but usually it is there.